# Add shortcut links to a user's IP log and cross-reference when tracing their IP address

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, moderator-tools

Moderators can see where a user is coming from using their IP address listed on their profile page. Clicking it brings up a nice little modal popup with some nuggets of info.

But when I want to find out more about a user's IP addresses or see who else has reported through the same addresses, I have to close the popup, click the mod link, choose the info tab and then choose the appropriate option.

Can we have shortcut links to these tools from the little IP address popup, since they're related anyway?

Comment: Can't see any of this, but how exciting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup now has a link that takes me to a page that displays all accounts seen at the IP address displayed on the user's profile. It's a single-IP version of the IP cross-reference tool, if you will.